# How to set unlimited timeout just for exact tasks

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, iis-7, timeout

We have a web based windows software with thousands of user. For some actions we send SMS and notification to many users. I don't want to set a long timeout on whole IIS settings. How can I set unlimited timeout only for sending messages?

this is the function that sends SMS to thousands of users:

```
for x=1 to 1000000
   call sendSMS(PhoneNumber(x),"test message")
next

function sendSMS(PhoneNumber,message)
    posturl="http://URL TO SMS SERVICE"
    posturl=posturl & "username=user"
    posturl=posturl & "&password=password"
    posturl=posturl & "&dstaddress=" & PhoneNumber
    posturl=posturl & "&message=" & server.Urlencode(message)

    set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.Open "POST",posturl,false
    xmlhttp.send
    myresult= xmlhttp.responseText
end function
```

Comment: In a time like this, you should seriously consider new technologies as they provide much simpler approaches (WebSockets/SignalR for example). Even if you cannot fully get rid of classic ASP, moving certain features to new stacks can save you some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`Server.ScriptTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524831%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property. You can set it to override the maximum amount of time that the script can run just for that request.

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 5000 ' or whatever
```

Note that it'd generally be best practice to not actually have the connection stay open for a long-running request, but put some sort of message in some sort of queue and have some sort of back-end service that handles the batch processing. But this approach may be adequate depending on your exact requirements.